# Proving a sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove $a^n/n! \rightarrow 0, n \rightarrow \infty$

So far, I have deduced that $1/n! < 1/ 2^{n-1}.$

But am stuck from there ... any hints/tricks

Comment: and what is $a$?

Comment: My mistake .... edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m$ be a positive integer such that $m > |a|$. Then, for all $n > m$ we have:

$0 \le \dfrac{a^n}{n!} = \dfrac{a^m}{m!} \cdot \dfrac{a}{m+1} \cdot \dfrac{a}{m+2} \cdots \dfrac{a}{n} < \dfrac{a^m}{m!}\cdot \dfrac{a^{n-m}}{m^{n-m}} = \dfrac{a^m}{m!}\cdot \left(\dfrac{a}{m}\right)^{n-m}$.

Now, use the squeeze theorem. Can you take it from here?

EDIT: I just noticed that I overlooked the possibility of $a$ being negative. The solution is now fixed.

Comment: Could you explain how you derived the upper bound ... as it is close to the upper bound I derived

Comment: I replaced the denominators $m+1$, $m+2$, ..., $n$ with something smaller, i.e. $m$.

Comment: Oh okay, and that clearly converges to 0 as m > a ... correct?

Comment: Yes, the right side is a geometric sequence with common ratio in the interval [0,1).

Answer (score 2):

$e^{a}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{n!}$ so $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{n!}$ converge so $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{n!}=0$

Comment: Does $e^a$ converge? Or are you saying that the series converges to $e^a$

Comment: $e^{a}$ is not something that you can ask whether it converge or not. It is a function that is indeed defined everywhere, and the fact that it equal to the series is just Taylor's series expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as a series see if that converges and if so recall the Divergence Test (what does that tell you elements converge too)

Answer (score 1):

For $n$ large enough $\frac{a}{n} < \frac{1}{2}$ so
the sequence will be bounded by $c\frac{1}{2^k} \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Sorry but what does c represent?

Comment: $c$ is some constant composed of those terms before the condition $\frac{a}{n}< \frac{1}{2}$ occurs. Sorry I should have explained that.